# hash map android issues

Tags: android, collections, hashmap

Why we add hash map in array list.For example

```
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hashMap.put("1","bmw");
            hashMap.put("2","mercedez");
            hashMap.put("3","audi");
            hashMap.put("4","sunny");

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            arrayList.add(hashMap);
```

Can we directly fetch data from hashmap like **hashMap("1");** like this

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Where do you find adding hashmap to arraylist?

Comment: people do that because they probably don't know the concept of java bean/model class.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly fetch data from hashmap like `hashMap.get("1");`

Comment: what does this answer means?

Comment: Sorry! My bad! Corrected @VivekMishra